# Show different div files while selecting different Select options

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Html file, where as per the input from Select file, I need to display some options.

So when I select Android or iOS, I need to show certain options and When I select Mac or Windows, some other options I need to show. I made the options into a div file.

so my javascript will look like

```
function checkvalue(val)
{
    if(val==="Android" || "iOS")
    {
        document.getElementById('mobile_device').style.display='none';
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('mobile_device').style.display='none'; 
    }

    if(val==="Windows " || "Mac ")
    {
        document.getElementById('desktop_device').style.display='block';
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('desktop_device').style.display='none'; 
    }
}
```

In Html

```
<b>Device Type : </b><select name = "type" id="type"  onchange='checkvalue(this.value)' select style="width:150px ; height:25px"><option>Android</option><option>iOS</option><option>Windows</option><option>Mac</option><option>General</option></select>


    <div id="mobile_device" style="display:none;"><font size="3"><b>Select the mobiles </b</font>
    </br></br>

    </div>
    <div id="desktop_device" style="display:none;">
    <font size="3"><b>Select the desktops :</b></font>

    </div>
```

But Its not showing properly. Whatever I select its showing the Desktop div only. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to assign values to your `option` tags. Second, you need to pass the selected text value perhaps like this

```
checkvalue(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

Next, your or statements should be like so

```
if(val === "Android" || val === "iOS")
{ // Should not be the same as the else clause. I'm guessing you meant block here
  document.getElementById('mobile_device').style.display='block';
}
else 
{ // Then this none makes sense.
  document.getElementById('mobile_device').style.display='none'; 
}
```